# Hiding later achievement levels

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have a series of achievements, (1k meters, 10k meters, 50k meters, etc) and I would like to hide the achievements later in the series until the level before it is unlocked. So at first only the 1k would be displayed, then once that was unlock 10k would be displayed, and so on.

I tried setting the achievements to 'hidden' but that makes them be displayed as 'Secret'. How can I completely hide the later achievements?

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/achievements#state), you can use `hidden` wherein the details about the achievement are hidden from the player. The Google Play games services provides a generic placeholder description and icon for the achievement while it's in a hidden state. *We recommend making an achievement hidden if it contains a spoiler you don't want to reveal about your game too early (for example, "Discover that you were a ghost all along!").* For your case, you need to use the [incremental achievements](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/achievements#incremental_achievements) since you want to display it per level. You can follow this [guide](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/achievements) on how to add achievements to your game.

> To unlock an achievement, call the unlock() method and and pass in the achievement ID.
>
> ```
> Games.Achievements.unlock(mGoogleApiClient, "my_achievement_id");
> ```
>
> **If the achievement is of the incremental type (that is, several steps are required to unlock it), call increment() instead.**
>
> ```
> Games.Achievements.increment(mGoogleApiClient, "my_incremental_achievment_id", 1);
> ```

Hope this helps!